# How do you find the optimal value for this function?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Given 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1,$$
what values of $x_i$ minimize the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\ ?$$

Comment: I assume you mean the following: Given $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$, minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$. I further assume you want $x_i$ real. It's not too difficult to show that the latter sum is minimized by $x_i = 1/n$ for all $i$, in which case the sum is $1/n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the method of Lagrange multipliers; but the problem is much more simple here.

You have an equation that defines a plane, and you want the vector on the plane that is closest to $\mathbf{0}$. The normal vector to the plane is $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, so you want to find the vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in the plane such that $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+t(1,1,\ldots,1) = (0,0,\ldots,0)$ for some $t$.

Hence we must have $x_1=\cdots=x_n$, and to lie on the plane you must have $nx_1=1$, so the answer is the vector
$(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n})$.

(This can also be seen by symmetry, since whatever the answer is, it should be invariant under swapping variables, since they all play symmetric roles).

Comment: +1.  A side comment on your parenthetic remark: It's not always true in the presence of symmetry that the optimal solution has all variables equal.  See, for instance, [When does symmetry in an optimization problem imply that all variables are equal at optimality?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58721/when-does-symmetry-in-an-optimization-problem-imply-that-all-variables-are-equal)

Comment: Of course, but in this example the objective is convex, in fact strictly convex.  So the minimum is unique, and therefore must be invariant under the symmetry.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Yes, as your comment on one of the answers in the linked question says! :)

Answer (score 5):

One way is to apply the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to two $n$-dimensional vectors $\mathit{\boldsymbol a}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $\mathit{\boldsymbol b}=(1,1,\ldots,1)$.

From $|\mathit{\boldsymbol a}\cdot\mathit{\boldsymbol b}|\le |\mathit{\boldsymbol a}||\mathit{\boldsymbol b}|$ it follows that $$|x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n|\le \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}\sqrt{1+1+\cdots+1}.$$

Since the left hand side equals $|1|=1$, 
$$\frac{1}{n}\le x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2.$$

The two sides are equal if and only if $\mathit{\boldsymbol a}$ and $\mathit{\boldsymbol b}$ are parallel, that is, $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n(=1/n)$.

Comment: The LHS had a small typo (there should be no $\sqrt{\cdot}$ there). I fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let  $S=\sum\limits_i x_i^2$. Define $z_i=x_i-h$ for $h=1/n$. One looks for the vector $(z_i)$ such that $\sum\limits_i z_i=0$ which minimizes
$$
S=\sum_i(z_i+h)^2=\sum_iz_i^2+2h\sum_iz_i+h^2\sum_i1=\sum_iz_i^2+2h\cdot0+h^2\cdot n=\sum_iz_i^2+h.
$$
Since $z_i^2\ge0$ for every $i$, the last expression of $S$ shows simultaneously that $S\ge h$ for every $(x_i)$ and that $S$ is minimal when $z_i=0$ for every $i$, that is, when $x_i=1/n$ for every $i$.